# Can a concept define an expression that satisfies itself?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to write a C++20 `concept` whose definition has an expression that will return a type that satisfies its own concept. However, it appears that C++ disallows the direct use of the concept name from within the concept definition <sup>(I guess it's incomplete at this point?)</sup>.

For example, the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept indirect_accessible = std::is_pointer<T>::value || requires(T t) {
    { t.operator->() } -> indirect_accessible;
};
```

<kbd>[live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1nanf4d7o)</kbd>

fails to compile with the error:

> ```
> <source>:6:27: error: expected concept name with optional arguments
> ```

Concepts can't be declared without being defined, so we can't introduce the name before the use through this technique. Similarly concepts can't seem to be template-specialized, so we can't provide a *different* definition for it.

Is there any way I can achieve this "recursive"-like definition of a `concept` in C++20?
If not recursively, are there any possible workarounds?

---

**Note:** my above example with `indirect_accessible` is just a simple application, but this applies for any type of "adapter"-pattern like concept expression.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56741456/817643 duplicate?

Comment: But how end the recursion?

Comment: There's also this https://stackoverflow.com/q/61920705/817643

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for bringing those to my attention; I guess there really isn't a great way to solve this particular problem. I was hoping that by having a terminating condition OR'd before the `requires` statement could solve this, but I guess not.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that the logical operator cannot prevent substitution.